# Parametrize EJB3 Remote URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm migrating an JavaEE5 application to JavaEE6. In that migration proccess, we have changed some architecturals parts, and now we have logic in a server, and presentation in another, and the comunication is via IIOP RMI Remote interface.

To do that, i have to define in my glassfish-web.xml the JNDI of EJB

```
<ejb-ref> 
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Informe</ejb-ref-name> 
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:srvtest:3701#java:global/mycrud/mycrud-dss-ejb/InformeBean!com.myorg.ejb.InformeRemote</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

But when I deploy on production enviroment I have to rewrite to

```
<ejb-ref> 
    <ejb-ref-name>ejb/Informe</ejb-ref-name> 
    <jndi-name>corbaname:iiop:srvproduction:3701#java:global/mycrud/mycrud-dss-ejb/InformeBean!com.myorg.ejb.InformeRemote</jndi-name>
</ejb-ref>
```

My point is that I have 3 enviroments:

- development
- testing
- production

And in any of them I have diferent servers names to access JNDI remote interfaces, and that are hardcoded in my descriptor. So I have to deal with maven, or ant to build differents ear or war, depending of the enviroment.

So my question is there any better way to deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same case as when using other target-specific configuration files, such as persistence configuration or application property files: You maintain different versions of the configuration file for your different target environments and then build a version for a specific one.

For Maven, you'll find a tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_profiles.htm).